# Look for div# in the response, if data is 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, response

I am using this script to insert comment to the database:

```
var http = createObject();
var nocache = 0;
function insert() {
document.getElementById('insert_response').innerHTML = "To Sek .. "
var fID= encodeURI(document.getElementById('fID').value);
var kommentar= encodeURI(document.getElementById('kommentar').value);
nocache = Math.random();
http.open('get', 'insert.php?fID='+fID+'&kommentar=' +kommentar+'&nocache = '+nocache);
http.onreadystatechange = insertReply;
http.send(null);
}
 function insertReply() {
 if(http.readyState == 4){
 var response = http.responseText;
 document.getElementById('insert_response').innerHTML = ''+response;
 }
}
```

Right now it innerHTML out the response text, that comes from insert.php.

But inside insert.php, i have setted up some "restrictions" in PHP like if empty, if double post etc. etc. I can therefore not place in: window.parent.showMessage("Video Is OK"); after if(http.readystate == 4)..

**So i would like to do another function to this script, that checks/looks for a div called #box and is containing "1", then it should:
window.parent.showMessage("Video Is OK");**

I use jquery too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ($("#box[value=1]").length > 0) { alert("Video is OK"); }
```

Comment: Where should i put this in my script?

Comment: Anywhere really.  Just put it on the page, in a script tag, that it references.   It'll run every time the page has completed loading.

Comment: I apologize.  I've changed the original code.  Put it after document.getElementById('insert_response').innerHTML = '' + response;... but still within the function.

Comment: And i cant really find anywhere in the code you wrote, where it search insert.php for #box/ response text?

Comment: That's what the selector does.  "#box:contains('1')" is a selector that searches the DOM for a div with an id of "box" whose inner html contains "1".

Comment: Okay. Ive did it like this:
document.getElementById('insert_response').innerHTML = response;
if ($("#box:contains('1')").length > 0) { alert("Video is OK"); }
and in the insert.php i have this:
<input type="hidden" id="box" value="1"> but it still doesnt give me an alert

Comment: Earlier, you said "box" was a div, not an input.... when did it change to an input?  Try changing the selector to: "#box[value=1]".  Updated the code again...

Comment: Thank you so much David, for helping out! And replying to my comments so fast. Im sorry ive said div instead of input, a little typo fail from my side.. sorry. This works perfect now. Thanks again, you were really helpful